# BrowserStack TestSwarm only pulls Windows OS's

Tags: node.js, browserstack, testswarm

I've recently setup an instance of TestSwarm that interfaces with BrowserStack by using the testswarm-browserstack nodejs module (https://github.com/clarkbox/testswarm-browserstack). I was referred to use the nodejs module from a link on BrowserStack site that walked through connecting TestSwarm to BrowserStack. Everything seems to be working as expected except that non-Windows OS's don't kick off in my automated process.

I have a bunch of OS X browsers configured on TestSwarm that seem to be configured correctly, they just never get launched during the automated runs. I'm able to join the swarm manually with BrowserStack, where I manually pull up an OS X browser and browse to the join url on my TestSwarm instance and it will properly pick up the browser and start running tests against it. The testswarm-browserstack nodejs module just seems like its ignoring the OS X browsers when it requests browsers from BrowserStack.

According the the documentation the testswarm-browserstack nodejs module should be able to handle OS X browser request as it uses BrowserStack API version 2.0 (https://github.com/clarkbox/testswarm-browserstack/pull/33)

Here is a small sample of how I'm specifying OS X browser in my TestSwarm configuration file:

```
            "OSX-10-6-FF-22-0": {
                    "browserFamily": "Firefox",
                    "browserMajor": "22",
                    "browserMinor": "0",
                    "osFamily": "Mac OS X",
                    "osMajor":"10",
                    "osMinor":"6"
            },
            "OSX-10-6-Safari-4": {
                    "browserFamily": "Safari",
                    "browserMajor": "4",
                    "browserMinor": "0",
                    "osFamily": "Mac OS X",
                    "osMajor":"10",
                    "osMinor":"6"
            },
```

Any incite would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I checked the link and can see the configuration is bit different. It specifies to mention browser, version and os. ex:

```
'Safari|5|0': {
  browser: 'safari',
  version: '5.0',
  os: 'mac'
}
```

So does BrowserStack expects. Check the api docs at https://github.com/browserstack/api. Do comment back if you have your own config translator.